# Color a specific word in a long text in c#

Tags: c#

I have some long text which contains a key word like "passed", "failed".
I am wondering how to color just the key work not the entire line.

Comment: are you using windows forms?

Comment: What kind of application you are targeting ? how you are displaying that string ? what you have already tried.

Comment: Use a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i use windowsforms and this string will be affected to an label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void  txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.CheckKeyword("passed", Color.Purple, 0);
            this.CheckKeyword("failed", Color.Green, 0);
        }
private void CheckKeyword(string word, Color color, int startIndex)
    {
        if (this.txt.Text.Contains(word))
        {
            int index = -1;
            int selectStart = this.Rchtxt.SelectionStart;

            while ((index = this.txt.Text.IndexOf(word, (index + 1))) != -1)
            {
                this.txt.Select((index + startIndex), word.Length);
                this.txt.SelectionColor = color;
                this.txt.Select(selectStart, 0);
                this.txt.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont have a specific event just a text to be affected to an label

Comment: Use the function and check for the label content